# codeduitestframework vs unittestframework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I am not able to understand the difference between Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework dll and Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework dll.

I have a coded UI test project which uses both of the dlls as a reference. And Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework dll used for [CodedUITest] attribute.

[image]

And if I remove the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework dll it gives me error message in [CodedUITest] attribute

Whereas whenever I create a new coded UI test project it does not use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework dll.And also the [CodedUITest] attribute is used from Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework dll.

[image]

What is the difference between them and If CodedUITestFramework dll is used for coded UI test why it is not used when I create a new Coded UI test project.

Can anyone please help?

Note : I am using Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to answer. Short version: they are different, they solve different use case: unit vs ui tests. And by nature they execute thing differently.

Long version: MSDN is your friend here - read up on unit and ui tests.

Comment: As I mentioned above I created one coded UI test project but codedUITestFramework dll was not add in it as you can see in picture above but then I did record action and did someactions in browser and generated the code and the codedUITestFramework dll got add to the proeject. After that I ran the test case it passed. And then I removed the reference codedUITestFramework dll and my test was passing even after removing it. Remember it was a UI test and not unit test. So that is why i am not able to understand why we have this dll if we can run test even without it.

Comment: I see, you have a reference to this nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework/ that is why you can remove the other .dll. They both have access to the attribute CodedUITest.

Comment: But it is in both of the projects. Then why it gives me error message of missing dll in first one and not in the second one.